# Nuget throwing 401 unauthorized error for no apparent reason

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I'm using VS2015 and Nuget to install external packages. Everything was working fine until today when Nuget started spitting out a:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)

I tried looking around for a solution, everyone is suggesting to provide again the credentials, either from the console or the UI under tools -> nuget package manager -> manage nuget packages for solution

No luck, what's going on here?

Comment: What`s your package source? Is VSTS feed? You need to check whether your account certification is out of date, or you can use another account to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved, I had to re-add my NuGet repository specifying username and password. For some reason VS2015 lost the credentials

Comment: This is still valid when changing from VS 2017 to VS 2019. I added a response to this issue on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56663816/285632

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem recently. The reason was password expiration for the user in the NuGet.config. After resetting, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sign in with correct user into vs2022 solved the issue for me